# I'm trying to connect my node to the parachain that im logging in with on my express backend

Tags: rococo, nodes, json-rpc, libp2p, peers

My goal is to be able to see the discover, incoming connection, and accepting connection in the parachain network, which I'm guessing should update the Idle 0 Peers to 1 Peer.
I'm still currently trying to fix this issue. If theres anything else that you need from me, please let me know!

This is my parachain terminal command. './target/release/polkadot-parachain --chain customSpecRaw.json --tmp --rpc-cors all --port 4003 --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods=unsafe --collator --detailed-log-output -l peerset=trace'

This is the result of me trying to connect the node to the polkadot-parachain:

2024-03-02 19:17:21.748 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Adding reserved node 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 on SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:21.749 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Connecting to 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 on SetId(0) (0/8 num_out/max_out).
2024-03-02 19:17:21.750 WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already reserved node 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 as reserved on SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:21.750 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Adding a new known peer 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6.
2024-03-02 19:17:21.750 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already known peer 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6, bumping last_updated.
2024-03-02 19:17:21.759 WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already reserved node 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 as reserved on SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:21.769 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Reserved peer 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 (Outbound) dropped from SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:21.769 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Peer 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 disconnected, reputation: -256 to -256
2024-03-02 19:17:21.899 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Connecting to 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 on SetId(0) (0/8 num_out/max_out).
2024-03-02 19:17:22.067 WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already reserved node 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 as reserved on SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:22.077 WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already reserved node 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 as reserved on SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:22.105 WARN tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already reserved node 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6 as reserved on SetId(0).
2024-03-02 19:17:22.193 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker peerset: [Parachain] Trying to add an already known peer 12D3KooWMi8BPM372mzMjtsiKjgHMDiSYFFgmJ58U8AeVsQNXAP6, bumping last_updated.

This is my express block of codes that I'm creating the node through js-libp2p.

const options = {

```
   peerId: peerId,
   addresses: {
       listen: ['/ip4/192.168.1.203/tcp/9944/ws']
   },
   transports: [
     tcp(),
     webSockets(),
     circuitRelayTransport({
       discoverRelays: 2,
     })
   ],
   connectionEncryption: [noise()],
   streamMuxers: [yamux(), mplex()],
   dht: kadDHT(),
   peerDiscovery: [
       mdns(),
       pubsubPeerDiscovery(),
       bootstrap({
           list: bootstrapNodes
       }),
   ],
   services: {
       identify: identify(),
       ping: ping({
           protocolPrefix: 'ipfs',
       }),
       dht: kadDHT({
           kBucketSize: 20,
           clientMode: false,
           broadcast: true,
       }),
       relay: circuitRelayServer(),
       pubsub: gossipsub({
           allowPublishToZeroPeers: true,
           emitSelf: true,
           floodPublish: false,
           gossipIncoming: true,
           doPX: false,
           directPeers: gossipPeers,
           allowedTopics: 'Login'
       })
   },
   config: {
       dht: {
           kBucketSize: 20,
           enabled: true,
           randomWalk: {
             enabled: true,
             interval: 300e3,
             timeout: 10e3
           }
       },
       pubsub: {
           enabled: true,
           emitSelf: false,
       },
       relay: {
           enabled: true,      
           hop: {
           enabled: true,    
           active: true      
           }
       },
       autoNAT: {
           enabled: true,
       },
   },
   connectionManager: {
       autoDial: true,
       maxConnections: 50,
       minConnections: 10,
   },
```

}

const node = await createLibp2p(options);

node.addEventListener('peer:discovery', async (event) => {

```
 const peerInfo = event.detail;
 console.log("New peer discovered", peerInfo.id.toString());

const rpcUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:9944';
  
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'system_addReservedPeer',
    params: [
      `/ip4/192.168.1.203/tcp/4003/ws/p2p/${peerId}`
    ],
    id: 2
  });

  const response = await fetch(rpcUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body
  });
```

})

node.addEventListener('peer:connect', async (event) => {

```
 console.log('peer connect', event.detail)
```

})

await node.start();
}